# Iterate through array while doing operation on all subsequent elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

I have an array of points. For each point, I want to draw the line crossing the current point and each subsequent point.

To do this efficiently I wanted to make sure to properly use Python's iterators. I thought about doing something like this:

```
i = 0
for p in points:
    head, *tail = points[i::]
    pairs = itertools.combinations(head, tail) # this is obviously wrong
    for (p1, p2) in pairs:
        get_line(p1, p2)
    i += 1
```

But I couldn't find a method in itertools that returns: (Head, Tail[0]) ; (Head, Tail[1]) ...etc.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: can you show us how your `points` look like, a sample input and a sample output

Comment: Your `i` never changes in your code. I'm guessing you intended to have `i += 1` each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to iterate the combinations. Something like this will get a line for every pair of points:

```
from itertools import combinations

points = [1, 2, 3, 4]

def get_line(p1, p2):
    print("line", p1, p2)

for pair in combinations(points, 2):
    get_line(*pair)
```

**prints:**

```
line 1 2
line 1 3
line 1 4
line 2 3
line 2 4
line 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

points = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']

for i, point1 in enumerate(points):
    for point2 in itertools.islice(points, i+1, None):  # iterator slicing
        print(point1, point2)
```

output

```
p1 p2
p1 p3
p1 p4
p2 p3
p2 p4
p3 p4
```